# How to design Notifications schema for Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, schema

Is it bette if I store notifications of all users under one collection:

```
{
id_: Object,
type: String, // post or message
ref_id: Number, // post id or message id
owner: Number,
read: Boolean,
created_at: Date 
}

// when I get notification for a single user
db.notifications.find({"owner": user_id, "read": {$ne: true}})
```

If you have an example please give me some advice or some link to study.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely recommended to store notifications in own table. This helps keeping your database clean and apples separated from peers. So your table might look like this

```
Notification
{
    id: int;
    sender: ForeignKey to user;
    receiver: ForeignKey to user;
    type: string; // or preferable ForeignKey to another table, in which you store possible types (see normalization of database)
    content: string;
    is_read: boolean;
    created_at: Date;
}
```

Comment: Yes we should have sender and receiver fields

Thanks for advice bro :)

Comment: What's the preferred way if I have multiple foreign keys? `type: string; // or preferable ForeignKey to another table, in which you store possible types (see normalization of database)`

Comment: @AbhiBurk yes, but that is not what OP required. Also, other functionality has to be rewritten

Comment: you can for example add field 'html' and store something like <a href='{url}'></a> for sake of generalizing